# Returning Data with Jquery and Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am writing a function on a webpage where when you type in a serial number, it will look up what model of part goes with that serial number in a SQL database.  Right now, the JsonResult is working and finding the correct information, but something is wrong with the jquery and ajax because it is not showing up after you click off of the serial number box (set with a blur, which does trigger as well).

Here is the controller code.

```
    public JsonResult SerialNumberSearch(string serialnum)
    {
        var result = db.IASerialNoMasters.Where(x => x.SerialNo == serialnum).Select(x => x.Model).Single().ToString();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is the script that I currently have on my View.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var serialnum;
    var url = '@Url.Action("SerialNumberSearch", "WarrantyRegistration")'
    $("#SerialNum").blur(function () {
        GetLiftModel();
    });
    function GetLiftModel() {
        serialnum = $("#SerialNum").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: { serialnum: serialnum },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#ModelName').val(data.Model);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

And this is the code for the textboxes on the View.

```
        <div class="row">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SerialNum, new { placeholder = "Serial #" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SerialNum, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="column-1">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ModelName, new { placeholder = "Model" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelName, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

Can anyone tell what I am missing from the function GetLiftModel area of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to show `data.Model`? In case you return `JsonResult` then `data` variable is in fact representation of your serial numbers and so it's probably that `data.Model` is in fact `undefined`.
Try change it to

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: url,
         data: { serialnum: serialnum },
         success: function(data) {
             $('#ModelName').val(data);
          }
       })
```

on the other hand based on fact you are returning just `string` there is no reason to return `JsonResult`. You could change signature of your controller method to

```
public JsonResult SerialNumberSearch(string serialnum)
{
    var result = db.IASerialNoMasters
                   .Where(x => x.SerialNo == serialnum)
                   .Select(x => x.Model).Single().ToString();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This ended up working, thank you!  I've been stuck on this for a couple hours now.  I just tested it and it brought in the correct part.

Comment: You're welcome. Also I'd recommend you to think about your LINQ query as well. What if there is no matching serial number? Now you're throwing exception while you could just let know client side and show this to UI gracefully.

Comment: Oh yes, I just finished with coding that.  I was just worried about getting the data to come through first before I started to complicate the code a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

This ultimately depends on what you want to access and if you need to access multiple properties :

- **Need a single property?** If you only need a single property, then you should be able to isolate that property out similar to your current code and only pass that back.
- **Need multiple properties?** Then you'll likely need to return the entire object or at least part of it from your `SerialNumberSearch()` method.

**Returning a Single Property**

Your current code has a final `ToString()` call that seems to indicate that you'll be returning just a single property, in this case the `Model` property  :

```
var result = db.IASerialNoMasters
               .Where(x => x.SerialNo == serialnum)
               .Select(x => x.Model)
               .Single()
               .ToString(); // This returns a string
```

Since that is the case, your `data` object that is being returned will already contain that specific property, and thus you'll just need to use `data` as seen below :

```
success: function(data) {
    // data will already contain your result, so just use it
    $('#ModelName').val(data);
}
```

**Returning Multiple Properties or an Object Graph**

If you expect to be able to access multiple properties from your object in JSON, you'll want to actually return the object itself and let the serializer handle passing it to Javascript so that it can be used as expected :

```
public JsonResult SerialNumberSearch(string serialnum)
{
    var result = db.IASerialNoMasters
                   .SingleOrDefault(x => x.SerialNo == serialnum);;
    if(result == null)
    {
         // Do something if it doesn't exist
         return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And then simply access the property you need from your `data` object within your Javascript code :

```
success: function(data) {
   // data will already contain your result, so just use it
   $('#ModelName').val(data.Model);
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion of removing the .ToString() did end up retrieving the same part for the serial number, Jaroslav's solution ended up bringing in the correct data.  Thank you for helping!

Comment: I've updated my response. Your original post wasn't super clear that `Model` was simply a string that was being returned (as I thought it was another class). Either way, I've added examples for handling either a single property or returning the entire graph, which should hopefully clarify things.

Comment: Ah sorry about that!  I'm pretty new to jquery and ajax, so I didn't realize there was a difference.